# Scroll to validated field in contact form 7 (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

Using Wordpress and the plugin Contact Form 7 I would like to use jQuery to scroll to the field that has failed validation.

This is the top of the form when no errors are detected:

```
<form action="/chanton/#wpcf7-f111-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Adding the invalid class when failing:

```
<form action="/chanton/#wpcf7-f111-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form invalid" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
```

The fields themselves receive the `wpcf7-not-valid` class.

I have added the following code to my theme however it is called on reload but doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('error being called');
    $(".wpcf7").on('invalid', function(e) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".wpcf7-not-valid").first().offset().top - 30
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First observation, ON is for events NOT classes.

try removing the period in .invalid. If that doesn't help change it to this:

```
$(".wpcf7 input").on("invalid", function(e) {
```

Comment: Sorry - that shouldn't have been there, I've tried both.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working fine for me, try this one.

```
/* Contact form 7 */
$(document).ready(function() {$(".wpcf7").on('wpcf7:invalid', function(e) {$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".wpcf7-not-valid").first().offset().top - 30}, 1000);});});
```

See demo [here](http://test.mariageatenerife.fr/contactez-votre-planificateur-de-mariage/)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, WPCF7 submissions should trigger ajaxComplete. try the following as your event handler:

```
jQuery('.wpcf7-form').ajaxComplete( function(){    
  if(jQuery(this).hasClass('invalid')){
    console.log('The form is invalid.');
    // Insert your code here
  }
});
```

Comment: Strange - just as a thought, try using a console message to see if the form is firing ajaxComplete at least. That will let you know if it's at least triggering the event you need to tie into.

Comment: It's not being called, is my form being submitted by AJAX?

Comment: WPCF7 says it supports AJAX form submissions, just to test I spun it up in a fresh WP field and my code works in console. Make sure you have it wrapped in document.ready or run it in the console before you submit the form.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wpcf7-form').ajaxComplete(function() {
        console.log('The form is invalid.');
        if ($(this).hasClass('invalid')) {
            console.log('The form is invalid.');
            scrollTop: $(".wpcf7-not-valid").first().offset().top - 30
        }

    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to fire an event on a class change, but your current method  won't really work.

My suggestion is 2 things.

1, if you can alter the function that makes the form invalid, then you should make your code a function and trigger it within the same block of code.

2, if that is NOT an option, you can make sure your form is contained within an element, like a div, and then you need to add a mutation event  listener:

```
var element = $('.wpcf7').get(0);

var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(attrModified);
});
observer.observe(element, { attributes: true, subtree: false });

function attrModified(mutation) {
   el=$(mutation.target);
   if(el.hasClass('invalid') && el.hasClass('wpcf7')){
     alert('Invalid'); //Change this to whatever should happen, in this case, a scroll. remember, el is your form. 
   }
}
```

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gregborbonus/w963mtkx/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple custom jquery event triggers on CF7.
Based on http://contactform7.com/2012/09/24/contact-form-7-33/

> New: Introduce 5 new jQuery custom event triggers (invalid.wpcf7,
>   spam.wpcf7, mailsent.wpcf7, mailfailed.wpcf7, submit.wpcf7).

so you can basically do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wpcf7").on('wpcf7:invalid', function(e) {
        //do something when submission is invalid
    });
});
```

Comment: Any idea when the invalid.wpcf7 and the submit.wpcf7 are triggered? The documention is non-existant..well I cant find it..

Answer (score 0):

```
;(function($){

  /**
   * Store scroll position for and set it after reload
   *
   * @return {boolean} [localStorage is available]
   */
  $.fn.scrollPosReaload = function(){
    if (localStorage) {
        var posReader = localStorage["posStorage"];
        if (posReader) {
            $(window).scrollTop(posReader);
            localStorage.removeItem("posStorage");
        }
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            localStorage["posStorage"] = $(window).scrollTop();
        });

        return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  /* ================================================== */

  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Feel free to set it for any element who trigger the reload
    $('select').scrollPosReaload();
  });

}(jQuery));
```

Found the one for you with thanks from the code written by Patrick Kahl - solves the problem - place script top of the page above the first div - in the div above the contact 7 form give a div id then place that div id in js script - viola - works like a charm - been looking for it for ages;

https://codepen.io/patrickkahl/pen/KFmAb

Give him many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.wpcf7-form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                if ($('.wpcf7-form').hasClass('invalid')) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(".wpcf7-not-valid").first().offset().top - 100
                    }, 2000);
          clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).